# yarn add react: error An unexpected error occurred:

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

```
yarn add react
yarn add v1.22.19
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.npmjs.org/react: connect ENETUNREACH 2606:4700::6810:1523:443".
```

Yarn-error.log

```
Arguments: 
  /home/oab/.nvm/versions/node/v18.13.0/bin/node /usr/local/bin/yarn add react

PATH: 
  /home/oab/.nvm/versions/node/v18.13.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Yarn version: 
  1.22.19

Node version: 
  18.13.0

Platform: 
  linux x64

Trace: 
  Error: connect ENETUNREACH 2606:4700::6810:1523:443
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1487:16)

npm manifest: 
  {
    "name": "01-configuranAPI",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "license": "MIT"
  }

yarn manifest: 
  No manifest

Lockfile: 
  No lockfile
```

I have already performed the following commands:

`yarn cache clean`

and nothing someone has the solution`
and nothing someone has the solution

Comment: It looks like network related. There was an issue with nodejs and npm packs in IPv6 network only. Is your network IPv6? 
Check some stuff here: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2519#issuecomment-774290146
And also try to force to work with ipv4 and disable ipv6 by adjusting sysctl.conf

Comment: Add react with npm install reactjs and share the results. Sometimes the public and nonsponsored npm repository, could have errors. Just try after some minutes.

Comment: npm i react
npm ERR! code ENETUNREACH
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ENETUNREACH
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/react failed, reason: connect ENETUNREACH 2606:4700::6810:1a23:443

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/oab/.npm/_logs/2023-02-18T22_30_34_967Z-debug-0.log

Comment: npm install reactjs
npm ERR! code ENETUNREACH
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ENETUNREACH
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/reactjs failed, reason: connect ENETUNREACH 2606:4700::6810:1a23:443

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/oab/.npm/_logs/2023-02-18T22_34_42_779Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Crowd! it was my internet provider. I couldn't believe he was blocking me.

Answer (score 2):

You can also force node to use ipv4 using env option

```
$> NODE_OPTIONS="--dns-result-order=ipv4first" yarn add react
```